# How can I use multiple channels in the same struct

Tags: go

In my code I want to do the following:

1. Recieve data from inputs as `event` and `message`
2. Format the received data based on the `event`

I thought to use something close to the method in the OOP, but it looks I meesed things up.

What I wrote is:

```golang
// Define the structs that contains the channels
type sseData struct {
    event, message string
}
type DataPasser struct {
    data       chan sseData
    logs       chan string
    connection chan struct{} // To control maximum allowed clients connections
}

// DEfine the struct's reciever that do the formating based on the input date
func (p *DataPasser) Format() {
    data := <-p.data
    switch {
    case len(data.event) > 0:
        p.logs <- fmt.Sprintf("event: %v\ndata: %v\n\n", data.event, data.message)
    case len(data.event) == 0:
        p.logs <- fmt.Sprintf("data: %v\n\n", data.message)
    }

}
```

Then I've the below:

```golang
func (p *DataPasser) HandleSignal(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/event-stream; charset=utf-8")
    w.Header().Set("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
    w.Header().Set("Connection", "keep-alive")
    setupCORS(&w, r)

    fmt.Println("Client connected from IP:", r.RemoteAddr)

    p.connection <- struct{}{}
    flusher, ok := w.(http.Flusher)
    if !ok {
        http.Error(w, "Internal error", 500)
        return
    }

    fmt.Fprint(w, "event: notification\ndata: Connection to WhatsApp server ...\n\n")
    flusher.Flush()

    // Connect to the WhatsApp client
    go Connect()

    // Prepare dataParser `p` to recieve data through its sseData channel
    go p.Format()


    for {
        select {
        case c := <-p.logs:
            fmt.Fprint(w, c)
            flusher.Flush()
        case <-r.Context().Done():
            <-p.connection
            fmt.Println("Connection closed")
            return
        }
    }
}

func setupCORS(w *http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    (*w).Header().Set("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
    (*w).Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    (*w).Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE")
    (*w).Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Accept, Content-Type, Content-Length, Accept-Encoding, X-CSRF-Token, Authorization")
}
```

Anf in the connect function, I've the:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
)

var err error

func Connect() {
    fmt.Println("Connected")
    if client.IsConnected() {
        client.Disconnect()
        passer.data <- sseData{
            event:   "notification",
            message: "Reconnecting to WhatsApp server ...",
        }
    }

    if client.Store.ID == nil {
        // No ID stored, new login
    GetQR:
        qrChan, _ := client.GetQRChannel(context.Background())
        err = client.Connect()
        if err != nil {
            //  panic(err)
            //passer.logs <- "Can not connect with WhatApp server, try again later"
            passer.data <- sseData{
                event:   "notification",
                message: "Can not connect with WhatApp server, try again later",
            }
            fmt.Println("Sorry", err)
        }

        for evt := range qrChan {
            switch evt.Event {
            case "success":
                {
                    //passer.logs <- "success"
                    passer.data <- sseData{
                        event:   "notification",
                        message: "success",
                    }
                    fmt.Println("Login event: success")
                }
            case "timeout":
                {
                    //passer.logs <- "timeout/Refreshing"
                    passer.data <- sseData{
                        event:   "notification",
                        message: "timeout/Refreshing",
                    }
                    fmt.Println("Login event: timeout")
                    goto GetQR
                }
            case "code":
                {
                    fmt.Println("new code recieved")
                    fmt.Println(evt.Code)
                    //passer.logs <- evt.Code
                    passer.data <- sseData{
                        event:   "qrCode",
                        message: evt.Code,
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        // Already logged in, just connect
        //passer.logs <- "Already logged"
        passer.data <- sseData{
            event:   "notification",
            message: "Already logged in",
        }
        fmt.Println("Already logged")
        err = client.Connect()
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }
    /*
        c := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
        signal.Notify(c, os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGTERM)

        <-c
        passer.data <- sseData{
            event:   "notification",
            message: "Server got shut down",
        }
    */
}
```

In the main file, I do have:

```golang
var passer *DataPasser

const maxClients = 1

func init() {
    passer = &DataPasser{
        data:       make(chan sseData),
        logs:       make(chan string),
        connection: make(chan struct{}, maxClients),
    }
}

func main() {

    http.HandleFunc("/sse", passer.HandleSignal)
    go http.ListenAndServe(":1234", nil)

    // Listen to Ctrl+C (you can also do something else that prevents the program from exiting)
    c := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(c, os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGTERM)

    <-c
    if client.IsConnected() {
        client.Disconnect()
    }
}
```

What is happeneing is that the server sending the first SSE correctly only, and it looks it hangs somewhere in the channel communication.

Any thought?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by writting:

```golang
    // Connect to the WhatsApp client
    go Connect()

    for {
        select {
        case data := <-p.data:
            fmt.Println("recieved")

            switch {
            case len(data.event) > 0:
                fmt.Fprintf(w, "event: %v\ndata: %v\n\n", data.event, data.message)
            case len(data.event) == 0:
                fmt.Fprintf(w, "data: %v\n\n", data.message)
            }
            flusher.Flush()
        case <-r.Context().Done():
            <-p.connection
            fmt.Println("Connection closed")
            return
        }
    }
```

But I still interested in splitting the action and using the reciever, I can not accept this as an answer, as it is a solution for the problem, but not an answer to the question.
Any thought?

Answer (score 0):

When you are sending data to `passer.data` from the `go connect()` routine, the routine `go p.Format()` is not listening. Because you are using an unbuffered channel for `parser.data` but no receiver is listening, your code is stuck. Either use a buffered channel for `parser.data` or make sure that your routine listening for incoming message from the data chan is started and listening before actually sending data to the channel. In your case, I guess starting the `Format` routine before the `Connect` routine should be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try swithcing the `Format` and `Connect` meanwhile can you provide example of the `buffered channel`?

Comment: exchanging `Format` and `Connect` order did not work :(